# Why is my block only executed once?

Tags: ruby

Why is it that:

```
array = (1..20).to_a
array.index.each_slice(5) do |slice|
  puts slice.inspect
end
```

returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

while:

```
other_array = []
array = (1..20).to_a
array.index.each_slice(5) do |slice|
  puts slice.inspect
  other_array.push(1)
end
```

returns only:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How does `other_array.push(1)` breaks the execution of the block? An obvious conclusion would be that I cannot access variables that are not in the scope of the block, but why is that?

Comment: Actually I do not see the point in calling `index` here (which is the cause, not the array push)

Comment: The documentation says that ```index``` "returns an Enumerator when neither a block nor argument is given", which is why I called ```index```. I though I needed an Enumerator to be able to call each_slice. It is only now that I see that Array includes the Module Enumerable and thus has the method each_slice itself.

Comment: One way of looking at this is `enum1 = array.index # => #<Enumerator: [1,..20]:index> ; enum2 = enum1.each_slice(5) #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1,..20]:index>:each_slice(5)>`. Examine this return value carefully. You can think of `enum2` as a "compound" enumerator. We can see the elements generated by `enum2` by converting it to an array: `enum2.to_a #=> [[1,...5],...[16,...20]]`. Then `enum2.each { |slice| puts slice.inspect } #=> [1,...5]...[16,...20]`. As you have noticed, you get the same result if `.index` is omitted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution in the array documentation. I wondered why you used the `index` function for the array when it seems like you just want to iterate over the array. For this you can use `array.each_slice` without invoking index.
Index says the following: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index

> Returns the index of the first object in ary such that the object is == to obj.
>
> If a block is given instead of an argument, returns the index of the first object for which the block returns true. Returns nil if no match is found

So your code evaluates the block and checks if the result is `true`.
In the first example you do only a `puts` which returns `nil`. Nil is false.
The second example returns an object of an array containing a single 1.
In ruby every condition is `true`, if it is not `false` or `nil`.
You can see this here:

```
if nil
   puts "foo"
end
=> nil

other_array = [1]
if other_array
  puts "foo"
end
=> "foo"
```

So the block in your second example returns something not-false so it will not run again, because it found a "valid" result.

For the return, you maybe should know that ruby returns the last expression in any scope, if no other return is given. So it returns `other_array`.
If you don't want to reformat your code you could to the following:

```
other_array = []
array = (1..20).to_a
array.index.each_slice(5) do |slice|
  puts slice.inspect
  other_array.push(1)
  nil 
end
```

This will force the block to return `nil` and the iteration will work.

Comment: It's more like a bug. The block is associated to the `each_slice(5)`, it should not affect the behavior of the `index` call. Besides, if the block is bounded to the `index` call, it should return `1` which is the first element, and calling `each_slice` on `1` should result in error.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I did not see that. It is weird why `index.each_slice` is actually working. index must return an array for this to work.

Comment: The documentation says that ```index``` "returns an Enumerator when neither a block nor argument is given", which is why I called ```index```. I though I needed an Enumerator to be able to call each_slice. It is only now that I see that Array includes the Module Enumerable and thus has the method each_slice itself.

Answer (score 2):

It seems tricky at the first glance, but if you check the docs for 
[`Array#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index) 
you'll see that this method return `Enum` if no block given.

Then you call `#each_slice(n)` on that `Enum` object with a block:

in the first case:

```
do |slice|
  puts slice.inspect
end
```

it returns `nil` each time to `#index` method. You'll get the same result if you call `array.index.each_slice(5) { nil }` or

in the second one:

```
do |slice|
  puts slice.inspect
  other_array.push(1)
end
```

value of this block getting evaluated inside block and returns `[1]` to the `#index` method, so it returns the first slice of the array. You'll get the same result if you call `array.index.each_slice(5) { any_non_falsy_object }`